# C++ как задать число больше чем 2147483647

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Пример кода:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main() {
    int a;
    cout << "Натуральное число:\n";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Последнее число: " << a % 10 << endl << "\n";
}
```

И при вводе длинных чисел (которые больше 2147483647) он выдаёт цифру 7.
Как решить, чтобы я мог вводить огромные числа?

Comment: Огромные - это сколько? До 2 в 64 степени — используйте тип `unsigned long long`.

Comment: а можно пример, как использовать данный тип?

Comment: всё, разобрался, спасибо огромное!

Comment: Ну и отлично. Но если вам надо только `a%10`, то читайте строку, и выводите последний прочитанный символ...

Answer (score 0):

Для чисел до 18446744073709551615 (обычно, теоретически тип `unsigned long long` может быть и не 8-байтным):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main() {
    unsigned long long a;
    cout << "Натуральное число:\n";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Последнее число: " << a % 10 << endl << "\n";
}
```